# Debugging a self hosted WebApi application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a WebApi application with the following controllor:

```
public class ContentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string contentType)
    {
        //do stuff
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The route looks like this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("content", 
    "api/content/{contentType}", 
    new { controller = "Content", contentType = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

When I host the service in IIS / cassini, if I POST to `api/content/whatever` then as expected, my controller action is hit.

However,

I've got a test project, that SelfHosts this api

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(Server))
{
    var result = client.PostAsync(BaseAddress + "api/content/whatever"

    var message = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

If I debug the unit test, and step into it, `result` is:

> {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], Headers:
>   {
>     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   }}

Unhelpfully, `message` is literally just

> An error has occurred

Is there a way I can debug my self hosted WebApi to find out what is causing this error?

**Set up**

`Server` is just an `HttpServer` from a base class, that holds my self hosted server, new'd up like so:

```
var httpConfig = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(BaseAddress);

new ApiServiceConfiguration(httpConfig).Configure();

var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(httpConfig);
server.OpenAsync().Wait();
Server = server;
```

Comment: (How) do you assign the routes to your server, does that happen in `ApiServiceConfiguration.Configure()`? Did you set the            `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` to `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always'?

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the detail I needed to find the issue. 
If you create an answer I'll accept it. For reference, this is the issue I'm having! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810754/debugging-a-self-hosted-webapi-application#comment29454920_19810754

Comment: @Alex I am having same issue. I want to debug my self hosted api. could you please refer me some solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable tracing and add a `Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener())` then you will get more detailed error messages.   However, your problem is most likely related to the fact that the object that you are trying to serialize is failing to serialize.

Answer (score 2):

Added to Startup

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

where `config` is of `HttpConfiguration` type.

This single line of code solved the same issue for me - now I can see all the inner exception's details.